# Laravel SQL Server Driver Error000000000

Tags: php, laravel

Getting `SQL-Server Connection error` in Laravel.

[image: SQL Server Driver Error]

I included `php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_74_ts`.
I have also updated `php.ini`.
But, still cannot fix this error.

Comment: can you check your phpinfo() to define your php version and 32bit/64bit? Also check the apacge error.log to define the issue when you start the apache server.

Answer (score 0):

You can download all Windows PHP SQL Server by the link below:-

[Windows PHP SQL Server Driver](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2120362)

Remember to copy the correct PHP version and correct system bits [x86 for 32 bit / x64 for 64 bit] .dll
paste to php/ext folder

Then enabled dll at php.ini

```
extension = [driver].dll
```

After that, required to install the correct version of ODBC Driver based on chart below:-

[image]

[Latest ODBC Driver Downloads Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

[Previous Version ODBC Driver Downloads Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/sql/connect/odbc/windows/release-notes-odbc-sql-server-windows?view=sql-server-2017#previous-releases)

```
Final step, don't forget to restart Apache server before do all kind of testing.
```

Comment: I use windows. Server default laravel artisan server. Still Error >could not find driver (SQL: select * from [employees]). could not find driver (0)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to connect with the mysql driver. Your error message indicates that this driver is unavailable.

Check that you have the mysql extension installed on your server.

In Ubuntu/Debian you check for the package with:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep php | grep mysql
```

Install the php-mysql package if you do not have it.

In Ubuntu/Debian you can use:

PHP7:

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

you will need to restart your web-server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Comment: I use windows. Server default laravel artisan server. Still Error >could not find driver (SQL: select * from [employees]). could not find driver (0)

Comment: restart your default server

Comment: you can approve my answer